# Clicking on a div changes position of nearby div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to do a todo app. I have things called as folders that can be added dynamically and we can add todo items inside each folder. All the list items are given an attribute of contenteditable. When I try to edit one of the list items, the position of the div below it gets changed. I don't know what is causing this. I have been at it for hours and haven't found any details.

[Image showing the folders getting realigned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1ZKv.png)

```js
var createFolder = function() {
  var folder = document.createElement("div");
  folder.classList.add("folder");
  folder.innerHTML = '<span id="deleteFolder" onclick="deleteFolder(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span> ' +
    '<span contenteditable="true" onfocusout="checkIfEmpty(this,\'New Folder\')">New Folder</span>' +
    ' <span id="newItem" class="addItem" onclick="addItem(this)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>' +
    '<ul class="list">' +
    '<li contenteditable="true" onfocusout="checkIfEmpty(this)" class="bigandspacy">New Item</li>' +
    '</ul>';
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(folder);
}

var checkIfEmpty = function(e, originalContent) {
  if (e.textContent === "") {
    e.textContent = originalContent || "New Item";
  }
}

var deleteFolder = function(e) {
  console.log(e.parentNode);
  document.getElementById("container").removeChild(e.parentNode);
}

var addItem = function(e) {
  var elem = document.createElement("li");
  elem.innerText = "New Item";
  elem.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
  elem.classList.add("bigandspacy");
  e.parentNode.children[3].appendChild(elem);
}

document.getElementById("newFolder").addEventListener('click', createFolder, false);
```

```css
body {
  background: #E1E1E4;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
}
.folder {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #2A2A33;
  width: 40vh;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  float: left;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.folder:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666 #E1E1E4;
}
.folder .fa-trash-o {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.addItem {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
.bigandspacy {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.bigandspacy:focus {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.bigandspacy:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button id="newFolder"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are required to post the complete, but minimal markup that shows the problem here. You have not shown any HTML or javascript.

Comment: Hi Rob, this is my first time and I thought dumping all those things is considered bad. I understand that the required codes are to be posted directly and will follow it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the input a transparent border so that it doesn't change size on focus:

```
.bigandspacy{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 5px; 
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

(Then just update the `border-color` on focus)

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/axs5ec89/2/

Comment: +1 Thanks. That did solve the problem but I quite don't understand what caused this. It would be helpful if you could explain the reason for it to behave like that.

Comment: The focus was causing your box to expand in width and height by 2px (1px on each side for the border of the input). Taking into account the total box size (including margin) this meant that a box to the left and underneath could no longer fit in the available space - in order for it to nicely flow they needed to all be the same dimensions

Comment: For variable dimension lists there are ways with `flex` to get things to fit better (but I don't think you need variable dimensions): https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20flex%20masonry

Comment: Thanks Dominic, I get it now. And thanks for the link. I will be needing it as these things can vary in length if we add more items in a particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a margin to the focus style - that will prevent the jump.

```
.bigandspacy:focus{
    border: 1px solid white;
    margin:-1px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Birgit Martinelle, I don't understand how changing the margin solves this?

Comment: well - the border is added around your textbox - so it adds one pixel to the size of your element - if you give it a margin of -1pixel you basically tell it to make the hovered element - the element that gets the border - 1 pixel smaller - which compensates for the increase and makes it exactly the same size - so no jumping.

Comment: Hi, I did make the change, but it didn't work. Here is a link to the image.  [Image of realigned folder](https://postimg.org/image/n9l9h282p/)

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I might have missed something earlier.